# How to execute codable values within viewDidload and Search option by name field using swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am using `codable` and trying to get `data` from `JSON` response. Here, I can’t able to print particular value into `viewDidload` using `swift 4.2` and I am using search but I want to assign `filteredData`  with name `values`.

my code

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let message: String
    let country: [Country]
    let cost: Double
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct Country: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let master: String
    let type, active: Int
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let id, userID, country, card: Int
    let category: Int
    let title, description: String
    let cost: Double
    let attachment, createDate, deviceID, appType: String
    let location: String
    let user: User
    let appTransCard: AppTransCard
    let appTransMaster: AppTransMaster

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case userID = "user_id"
        case country, card, category, title, description, cost, attachment
        case createDate = "create_date"
        case deviceID = "device_id"
        case appType = "app_type"
        case location, user
        case appTransCard = "app_trans_card"
        case appTransMaster = "app_trans_master"
    }
}

struct AppTransCard: Codable {
    let card: String
}

struct AppTransMaster: Codable {
    let master: String
}

struct User: Codable {
    let firstname, lastname: String
}
```

I need to get values within `viewdidload` from `Root.cost.`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    // here I need to print Root.cost value
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your current result and what is your expected result?

Comment: First I need to print Root.cost within viewDidload, I don't know how to get it and print it within viewDidload. Second user of name values I am using for search, I need to know how to implement basic tableview search with JSON first name value. I would like to learn I tried my best but didn't find best result. @ Matic Oblak

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new variable of type `Root`
for example `var root : Root`
and on viewDidLoad you make the request (decode)
depend if it's from API or local JSON file.
and then the result from the decode will save inside root variable

`root = result`

then you can access `root.cost`

I also recommend you to see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY3bTxgxWss)
it will help you understand how to use decodable

Comment: I give to you the big picture, on how you will do it, to help you more give us a sample of the JSON file and what you did try and what do you expect?

Comment: As per your answer I am done get root.cost. It  is working. Now I am trying to implement search bar with tableview. here I am loading tableview array from the JSON response filteredData = tableArray (How to assign name here) if I assigned my search will work.@Basil

Comment: you need to use `NSPredicate` to search the array and the result you will save it to the new array `filteredData`
then use the `filteredData` in `cellForRow` to display the search result

Comment: Could you please provide some sample? @Basil

Comment: the idea is you need to add `UISearchResultsUpdating`
`func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredTableData.removeAll()

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (tableData as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
`

Comment: Follow this article: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-ios-tutorial .
I recommend you to learn how to search before learning how to code